# Is delta-epsilon proof necessary for multivariable limits?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

The specific problem is from James Stewart's 7th edition of Multivariable Calculus. The problem is $$\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\frac{x^2y}{\:x^2+y^2}\right)$$ To evaluate this limit, do I need to use the delta epsilon proof? Is there no algebraic way to do this?

Comment: With *all* limits, there is the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition and then there are various tools, techniques and theorems that help you avoid using the definition directly. This is the case for everything in mathematics. There is the base theory with the base definitions and then there is a very complicated world full of results that have been collected over decades or centuries. To evaluate the limit, or to do work within a certain area, all these things are at your disposal. I'm being a bit grandiose here but my point is: $\delta$-$\epsilon$ is the beginning, not the end. A proof is a proof.

Comment: I took the time to write that because I get a bit annoyed about this idea of $\delta$-$\epsilon$ being an all-important device, special somehow. A proof by any means is still a proof; what matters is the argument.

Comment: Yeah I understand that  δ-ϵ is not the only way to show a limit. I was just unaware of any techniques to do so without it for this particular limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the squeeze theorem:
$$0\le \left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2} \right|\le \left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2} \right|=|y| \to 0 $$
Otherwise, you can use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are required to do it using delta-epsilon, which I'm sure it is a real nightmare giving a look at the function, you should apply algebraic methods. For example, do you know about polar coordinates? In this new system of coordinates, $(x,y) = (r \cos \theta,r \sin \theta)$. It is easy to see that if $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0), r \rightarrow 0$, and therefore the limit would be with the condition $r \rightarrow 0$. This is, $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{r^2 \cos \theta \cdot r \sin \theta}{r^2} = \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} r \cos \theta \sin \theta = 0$$